# GROK or Regex to get filename ending with.jar

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to parse a field in logstash using Grok or Regex.
I want to get all the process names ending with **.jar** and put them in a field called **"subprocess"**
Sample data is something like this

```
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java -server -Xms256m - Xms512m -XX:CompileThreshold=7000 -cp /opt/fmw/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-launcher.jar -Dlaunch.use.env.classpat
```

I have tried  following so far

```
.*\.jar$          #This works on regex101.com but not in logstash
(?<subprocess>[$.*\w.jar$])    #This only gives j in subprocess
```

Any regex pattern that can extract **"weblogic-launcher.jar"** and put it in field **"subprocess"** would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my question, Thanks

Comment: Try `(?<subprocess>[^/]+\.jar)` or `(?<subprocess>[^/]+\.jar)\b`, see https://regex101.com/r/idOV1Z/1

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor - This worked
But I have another log which is something like this
`/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java -server -Xms256m - Xms512m -XX:CompileThreshold=7000 -cp /opt/fmw/middleware/wlserver/server/lib - jar process.jar -Dlaunch.use.env.classpat`
In this case the regex is getting everything till **.jar** but I want it to pull only **process.jar**

FYI, I am testing it on Kibana Debugger
I tried `(?<subprocess>[^/]+.jar)\b` but it didn't work

Can you please explain how is it working?
I tried

Comment: Also what if some log has multiple **.jar** processes in same line

Comment: Seems to work, too - https://regex101.com/r/idOV1Z/2

Comment: Yep but it is picking **lib - jar process.jar**
I want only **process.jar**

Comment: Then use `/[^/]*?(?<subprocess>[^/\s]+\.jar)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/idOV1Z/3). I can post an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/[^/]*?(?<subprocess>[^/\s]+\.jar)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/idOV1Z/3).

**Details**

- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]*?` - zero or more, but as few as possible, chars other than `/`
- `(?<subprocess>[^/\s]+\.jar)` - Group "subprocess": one or more chars other than `/` and whitespace and then `.jar` string.